# name of database to php function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to make php Function where I will send database name (I use MSSQL 2008):

```
function get_query($database)
(
    $query = ";WITH [cteRows] AS
    (
        SELECT  [nazwa],
                [wartosc],
                [czas],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
        FROM ('$database')
        WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
        AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
        AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
    )";
return $query;
)
$database1 = '[test].[dbo].[coldbox7]';
$query1 = get_query($database1);
```

if I make:

```
FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7]
```

is all ok.
could you tell me how should I send database name to query?

Comment: `from $database`. there's no need whatsoever for those `('...')`. `'...'` is not a table/field identifier. It's a **STRING**

Comment: I understand that I should write FROM $database, but it doesn't work also.
STRING HAS[code] '[test].[dbo].[coldbox7]' [/code]and I need only [code][test].[dbo].[coldbox7][/code]

Comment: then have the db TELL you why it failed. e.g. `$result = mssql_query($sql) or die(mssql_get_last_message())` or whatever the equivalent would be for the db library you're using.